# haproxy logs - depends on conditionals

Tags: logging, proxy, haproxy

I am fencing some issue with log-format on haproxy setup. First of all I have multiple proxies setup which means:

> request -> client-proxy -> mid-proxy -> application

Regarding to this on client-proxy I am adding:

> unique-id-header X-Unique-ID

and this value is represented on logs as:

> log-format %ci:%cp\ [%t]\ %f\ %b/%s\ %Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt\ %ST\ %B\
>   %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ {%hrl}\ {%hsl}\ %{+Q}r\
>   {%ID}

which is great. On the other hands on mid-proxy I am able to get this value from header on frontend:

> capture request  header    X-Unique-ID         len 200

And now on this proxy (mid-proxy) I have such condition:

> acl uniq_header_exist hdr_cnt(X-Unique-ID) eq 0
>
> http-request set-header X-Unique-ID %{+X}o\ %ci:%cp_%fi:%fp_%Ts_%rt:%pid if
>   uniq_header_exist

(which does the job so I am able to add uuid if not exist - great) and logs are represent like:

> log-format %ci:%cp\ [%t]\ %f\ %b/%s\ %Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt\ %ST\ %B\
>   %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ {%hrl}\ {%hsl}\ %{+Q}r\
>   [id=%[capture.req.hdr(2)]]

but I cant get any possibility to do sth like:

```
if X-Unique-ID exist then use:
  log-format XXXXX
else
  log-format YYYY
```

any suggestion?

Or if you have some example setup how can we add **haproxy uuid header if exist or if not and how to log it.** All is quite simple with one frontend proxy.

Thanks for any help!